# Python e-mailing? Easiest way?

Tags: python, email

How can I send an e-mail from Python without any third party programs?

Comment: Just to emphasise this point, email is sent through a SMTP server, which you will need if you want to send email. Your ISP may provide one; otherwise, you will need to get one some other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the python [email](http://docs.python.org/library/email.html) and [smtplib](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html) modules. Examples: http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html

Comment: What does this part mean?

` Send the message via our own SMTP server, but don't include the
# envelope header.
s = smtplib.SMTP()
s.sendmail(me, [you], msg.as_string())
s.quit()`

Comment: @JSHoe, it creates a new SMTP connection using [`smtplib.SMTP`](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP), sends an email using [`sendmail`](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail) and terminates the SMTP connection using [`quit`](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.quit). Does that make it any clearer?

Comment: What I mean is, what do I need to enter into all those parts?

Comment: Well, for the `smtplib.SMTP` function you have to add your SMTP server details, like the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP) says. The `sendmail` function is well documented in both the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail) and in the example. I'm not sure what else to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

[`smtplib`](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html)

You need an SMTP server to send mail with, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Python comes with an email module:
http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html

Note though that you still need to contend with a host of emailing issues unrelated to Python, like setting up your SMTP server. I hope you aren't intending to spam.